# Able to change private const class member

Tags: c++

Why does c++ allow changing private member(const or not) from outside class. 
No one outside the class should be able to change a const member. This seems to be breaking the c++ encapsulation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

class A
{
    const std::string s;
    public:

    A():s{"abcd"}{};
    const std::string& f()
    {
        return s;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::string &s = const_cast<std::string&>(a.f());
    s="efgh";
    std::cout<<s<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<a.f()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation was done using c++11 on wandbox online compiler.

```
g++ prog.cc -Wall -Wextra -I/opt/wandbox/boost-1.69.0/gcc-head/include -std=c++11
```

Output is:

```
efgh
efgh
```

I expected compilation error on:
    std::string &s = const_cast(a.f());

I should not be allowed to change a private class member(const or non const) from outside in any way if there are no methods to do so.

Comment: You aren't allowed to change a const object. What you did is undefined behavior. On the other hand you are allowed to access private members if they are exposed through public functions.

Comment: You can't. If you had just written `std::string s = a.f();` the compiler would error, but you are telling the compiler "hey I know what I'm doing" when you `const_cast`

Comment: SO is it undefined behaviour or compiler trusts what I am doing?

Comment: C++ is full of ways to force the compiler to accept code, but in many cases this just moves it from "ill-formed with a diagnostic message" to "undefined behavior without any diagnostic". Yes C++ assumes you know what you are doing and that if you do something unusual (like `const_cast`) you verified that you are indeed allowed to do so with defined behavior. To know whether it is defined or undefined you need to read the C++ standard or a reference carefully. Here it is undefined behavior as explained in the answer.

Comment: Thanks guys. Got it. So basically the point is "don't do these adventures".

Answer (score 3):

That's undefined behavior.

The fact that it allows you to do it doesn't mean that is right, modifying a `const` object through a non const one is undefined behavior, anything can happen, including the appearance of working.

> I should not be allowed to change a private class member(const or non const) from outside in any way if there are no methods to do so.

Accessibility of data members is somewhat unrelated to accessibility of member functions and what they do, you can have private members and public functions that alter or give certain access to them without violating the inherent properties of the members. In your example `foo` is returning a ref to `const std::string` which express clearly the intent (*it's a const object*) but then outside you're violating that intent.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't.

When you stripped away the `const` with a `const_cast`, you literally turned off the protection that you're asking about. That was *your* responsibility. C++ has to permit this to allow "hacks" in the general case; per its philosophy, it makes no serious effort to stop you from breaking the contract. But, ultimately, you did break a contract, so it's your fault!

Your program has undefined behaviour as a result; i.e. the code is broken.

The bypassing of `private` is totally fine as you directly exposed the member through a member function. (Access specifiers protect *names*, not objects, and your `main` does not use the private name.) Again, that was your choice. *You* broke the class's encapsulation.